# Python inserting multiple elements in one iteration in list comprehension conditionally

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

Suppose we have to insert two elements in a list comprehension in one iteration, but we have to choose which two to insert. How do we make such a list comprehension.

For example:- 
Suppose we have a list `hostnames = ['aa', 'bb', 'dd', 'pp', 'bb', 'zz', 'hh']`.

Now we want to modify this list such that hostnames starting with p should have an extra element called '_prd' ( eg. 'pp_prd') and similarly an extra element for hostnames starting with h with the value '_uat'.(eg 'hh_uat').

So the desired output for the above list would be `mod_hostnames = ['aa', 'bb', 'dd', 'pp_prd', 'pp', 'bb', 'zz', 'hh_uat','hh']`.

Now I thought of writing it out like this -

```
>>> fh=lambda x: x+'_uat'
>>> fp=lambda x:x+'_prd'
>>> fo=lambda x:x
>>> lis
['aa', 'bb', 'dd', 'pp', 'bb', 'zz', 'hh']
>>> hostnames = lis
>>> mod_hostnames = [f(host) for f in (fo,fp) if host[0]=='p' else f(host) for f in (fo,fh) if host[0]=='h' else host for host in hostnames]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    mod_hostnames = [f(host) for f in (fo,fp) if host[0]=='p' else f(host) for f in (fo,fh) if host[0]=='h' else host for host in hostnames]
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

We get a syntax error. I also know that in list comprehensions the second loop runs faster (just like in for loops) and in our code, the `host in hostnames` is running faster instead of the other desired way round. So I tried this :-

```
>>> mod_hostnames = [f(host) for host in hostnames for f in (fo,fp) if host[0]=='p' else for f in (fo,fh) if host[0]=='h' else for f in (fo)]  
File "<stdin>", line 1
    mod_hostnames = [f(host) for host in hostnames for f in (fo,fp) if host[0]=='p' else for f in (fo,fh) if host[0]=='h' else for f in (fo)]
                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any suggestions? Or is this not possible in list comprehensions. 
I know that this is not readable at all and there are much better ways to write this out. (eg using a dict 'switch' to write this in one statement inside a for loop, or the good old if else in a loop, etc).

Post solution edit: Received wonderful responses. Thanks! Can someone explain why the code I posted is wrong as well?
I feel its because the statements evaluated when condition is true or false just resolve to an empty for loop: `for f in (fo,fp) if host[0]=='p' else for f in (fo,fh)` if host[0]=='p' the program goes to an empty for loop `for f in (fo,fp)`. Is this correct? 
A reverse engineering of my faulty comprehension into a for loop would clear this up I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's better to start with a traditional `for` loop, that way you can have a glimpse of what's difficult:

```
mod_hostnames = []
for name in hostnames:
    if name.startswith('p'):
        r = [name + '_prd', name]
    elif name.startswith('h'):
        r = [name + '_uat', name]
    else:
        r = [name]
    mod_hostnames.extend(r)

assert mod_hostnames == ['aa', 'bb', 'dd', 'pp_prd', 'pp', 'bb', 'zz', 'hh_uat', 'hh']
```

To create a comprehension list, you need to transform the `if` ... `elif` ... `else` statement in a one-line statement using ... `if` ... `else` ...

You can process as follow:

```
mod_hostnames = []
for name in hostnames:
    r = [name + '_prd', name] if name.startswith('p') else \
        ([name + '_uat', name] if name.startswith('h') else [name])
    mod_hostnames.extend(r)
```

Well, it becomes a little tricky.

To transform this loop into a comprehension list, you'll need to iterate over the `r` value. You'll get a comprehension list inside a comprehension list.

```
mod_hostnames = [item
                 for name in hostnames
                 for item in ([name + '_prd', name] if name.startswith('p') else
                              ([name + '_uat', name] if name.startswith('h') else [name]))]
```

Hum! I think it is too complex to keep a comprehension list. Who will want to debug that?

For maintainability, I suggest a solution with a small function:

```
def modify(name):
    if name.startswith('p'):
        return [name + '_prd', name]
    elif name.startswith('h'):
        return [name + '_uat', name]
    else:
        return [name]


mod_hostnames = [item
                 for name in hostnames
                 for item in modify(name)]
```

Here it is!

Comment: Thanks Laurent! Choosing this as the correct answer as this goes more into depth about the process of creating list comprehensions. I encourage readers to check out @pault's answer too as it maintains the questions syntax and thus might be more readable to readers looking for a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to write a transformation function which always returns *tuples*, using singleton tuples when necessary:

```
def transform(name):
    if name.startswith("p"):
        return (name + "_prd", name)
    if name.startswith("h"):
        return (name + "_uat", name)
    return (name,) # Singleton tuple.
```

Then you can do this:

```
import itertools
mod_hostnames = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    transform(name) for name in hostnames))
print(mod_hostnames)
```

`itertools.chain.from_iterable` is essentially a flatten operation which concatenates all the intermediate tuples, and the outer `list` turns the output from that generator into an actual list.

However, in such cases, a more pedestrian approach with a traditional `for` loop makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution and exposing a module which might benefit others in other instances. I did come across this while perusing stack overflow  for the solution to this question but felt including this in the question would make it too long and confusing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is okay, but your syntax was incorrect. Here is a way to modify your existing code:

```
mod_hostnames = [
    f(host) for host in hostnames 
    for f in (
        (fo,fp) if host.startswith('p') else 
        (fo,fh) if host.startswith('h') else 
        (fo,)
    )
]
print(mod_hostnames)
#['aa', 'bb', 'dd', 'pp', 'pp_prd', 'bb', 'zz', 'hh', 'hh_uat']
```

Wrap the `if`/`else` to modify the iterable for `f` with parentheses, and also you need the trailing comma in `(fo,)` to make it a tuple.

You can also use `str.startswith` instead of indexing the first character in the string.

In any case, a traditional loop is perfectly fine here and may be preferable for readability/ease of understanding:

```
mod_hostnames = []
for host in hostnames:
    mod_hostnames.append(fo(host))
    if host.startswith('p'):
        mod_hostnames.append(fp(host))
    elif host.startswith('h'):
        mod_hostnames.append(fh(host))
```

Comment: Very concise solution! I actually understood the solution from this answer first instead of the selected one because this maintains the question syntax and is readable with just a glance.
pault I hope its okay with you that I selected Laurent's answer as correct because it goes more into depth ( and eliminates the lambda functions too!).
Mods are welcome to modify or remove this comment if it seems cluttery or unnecessary, I just felt pault deserves an explanation since he posted first.

Answer (score 0):

Using *list comprehension* with `if` , `else if`, `else` and using `set`

```
mod = [i +'_prd' if i.startswith('p') else i + '_uat' if i.startswith('h') else i for i in hostnames]
mod = sorted(list(set(mod) | set(hostnames)))
# ['aa', 'bb', 'dd', 'hh', 'hh_uat', 'pp', 'pp_prd', 'zz']
```

Comment: @pault fixed required additional line to accomplish used `set` could it be accomplished without set?

Comment: This seems to meet OP's requirements, assuming that the original order of elements doesn't matter. There are ways without `set`, as shown in the other answers.

Comment: @pault yeah I double checked there is no mention of the new item being before or after even though output displays, he stated just to create the item, hope this works

Comment: Yes order is not important.